# Nested Jira Search on two independent projects

Tags: jira, python-jira

I need to get a nested Jira search. I am okay with JQL query but I have a usecase that I don't know how to solve

1. Company uses project=XTBOW for reporting purpose for executives (Epic)
2. The company also uses project=XTA for underling development work (Task)
3. The XTA task are linked to the XTBOW Epic for a subset of task, but not all. (There is a large body of XTA task that are not linked to XTBOW)

I need to get a filter going for all XTA projects that are linked to XTBOW Epics only. I would like to use a filter like this:

```
project = XTA and "Epic Link" in (<project = XTBOW.key>)
```

I can manually prove this filter works. But need a way to automate this filter, because the number of tickets being created/tracked in growing exponentially, and if someone deletes a key for XTBOW that is in the "Epic Link" field, the JQL search throws and error because the "Key" is missing.

Example - FYI cf[10231] is the "Epic Link" field:

```
project in (XTA,XTWOF) and cf[10231] in (XTBOW-42,XTBOW-59)
```

The overall objective is to download the data to a dataframe. So if there is a better suggestion to even avoid JQL and do it through python. I am all ears. Just need so pointers to start. I am just going this route because I have already built a JIRA-Downloader/Parser using Python.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get subsets of issues is with:

```
search_issues(jql_str, startAt=0, maxResults=50, validate_query=True, fields=None, expand=None, json_result=None)
```

You should be able to just pull the issue sets using the queries you already created, just make them into strings.

[DOC](http://search_issues(jql_str,%20startAt=0,%20maxResults=50,%20validate_query=True,%20fields=None,%20expand=None,%20json_result=None))